# Hide popup keyboard on Corona (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, coronasdk

I am trying to have a hidden textfield which takes the number from a barcode scanner (via bluetooth). The scanner output is just regular text. To do this I have placed the text field off screen and set the keyboard focus automatically to this field (native.setKeyboardFocus(barcodeField)) which captures the barcode once it is read.

The only problem is the keyboard pops up while the scanner isn't connected. Is there any way to have the keyboard hidden but the text field still focused on? So that when the BT scanner is connected and a barcode is scanned, the text field will capture the code. Or any better solutions?

Thanks

Comment: u want to hide the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `native.setKeyboardFocus` function, that gets a textField or a textBox and set the keyboard on it. you can write:
`native.setKeyboardFocus( nil )` 
to set the keyboard focus nothing.